# if a ray doesn't include a point at it's end what is it's end point

Tags: linear-algebra

if a ray that goes up to a point but doesn't touch it, the point is signified by a open circle.  If there is an open circe at say (1, 1) at the end of a ray, and the ray has the slope 1 and passes through the origin (and goes an infinate amount to the left), what would be the end point on the right side of the ray?  In other words if the domain was (-infinity, x] and the range was (-infinity, y], what would x and y be?

Comment: "If a ray doesn't have an end point then what is its end point"

Comment: if someone asked you the local max, what would you say?

Comment: A few things. First, a ray, by definition is a directed line starting at a point an continuing forever in a direction so what you are asking about is not a ray. Second, this object you are asking about would NOT have an endpoint. Third, I am not sure precisely what you mean by "local max" but anything that you could mean I suspect the answer is "there is no local max".

Comment: I mean local max as in if it were a sine wave the peak of every wave would be a local max, I thoight I could bescrobe the problem using a ray but I guess nit, thanks.

Comment: There's something called a "limit point" of the ray -- a point it gets arbitrarily close to, but doesn't quite touch. The empty circle is a limit point of the ray. (Like Zachary said, not technically a ray -- but I think if you said "open ray" everyone would understand exactly what you meant, so we can call it that.) The equivalent in terms of the sine function would be a "supremum". A supremum is like a maximum, but isn't necessarily reached: it just gets arbitrarily close. Like $1+\pi/2$ is a supremum of $\arctan(x)+\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

> "If a ray doesn't have an end point then what is its end point?" – Zachary Selk

Succinctly so.

The linear segment, $\{(x,y): y=x+a, x<b\}$ does *not* have a maximum $y$ value.   Nor a maximum $x$, for that matter.   The point $(b,a+b)$ does not lie in the interior of the set.

You are essentially asking what is $\max\{y\mid y\in (-\infty; a+b)\}$.   It does not exist because the interval is open above.

$$\neg \exists y_\max\in (-\infty;a+b)~\forall y\in (-\infty;a+b): y_\max\geq y$$

> What is the value of something defined not to exist?

Comment: I was asking more about how to represent it, like you cant count to infinity, but there is a symbol for it.